# Problemas al aplicar tipo de letra a una firma de correo

Tags: css, html5

Buenas tardes intento poner este texto en la firma de correo de zoo mail pero no agarra el tipo de letra.

> Como debería de quedar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Como quedo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Este es mi código donde jalo el estilo de letra.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Exo';font-size: 22px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Exo</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>123456790</p>
<p>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</p>
<p>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar. 
Gracias

Comment: El código esta correcto. Al ejecutar tu código me sale como el que usted muestra arriba. Si el problema sigue persistiendo puede que sea problema de tu buscador. Prueba con Google Chrome. Si te da fallo también con ese navegador trata de borrar las cookies. Un saludo. Espero haberle ayudado.

Comment: Hola Javier, al parecer si esta cargando un tipo de letra pero no es "Exo", te sugiero realizar en tu browser Ctrl+F5 y prueba nuevamente, posiblemente definiste otra fuente y se quedo cache . @Javierfr

Answer (score 0):

El problema en este caso parece ser caché, definiste una fuente anteriormente, te sugiero <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> para que elimines caché,

Lo que muestras se muestra si usas otro tipo de fuente:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Verdana';font-size: 22px;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]